# Best and easiest way to build a Product Roadmap?

Tags: roadmaps

My product owner wants me to show him a product roadmap based on what will be released quarterly, right now all planning is done on a week by week basis which seems to be working well but is not giving him an idea of what we are trying to achieve long term. I have explored the following options:

- Gaant
- Release burn up charts

I am not satisfied with any, since they are too detailed or not visual enough.

What tools do you use to represent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar experience here, and I finally decided to maintain two documents:

- One Micro plan using gantt to schedule tasks for the next week (so reviewed weekly)
- One Macro roadmap with a simple spreadsheet document in order to have an overview of the release on a monthly/quarterly basis of each modules, which looks like this:
  [image: Roadmap]

Comment: How did you create that ?

Comment: That's just a spreadsheet used graphically. Not usually recommended but it served my purpose.

Comment: Did you build it? Do you find that the product roadmap often changes

Comment: Yes we did, this overall roadmap doesn't change much, sometimes we need to re-calibrate and extends the work on a module of one month but that's it. The micro plan using a gantt chart is the one changing weekly depending of the progress on each task.

Comment: Has your stakeholder found having a product roadmap in that format helpful?

Comment: Remember that who says what is priority is the Product Owner. You can help him, give him a start point, but if can't let him just approve the document and never look at it again for a long time. You will probably something that he does not want/need and make him loses tons of money.

Comment: @LucPavot created and showed my boss the product roadmap in this format, he was very happy. Thank you Luc!

Comment: @bobo2000 I'm glad it worked out :)

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to create a Goal Orientated Roadmap as detailed [here](http://www.romanpichler.com/tools/product-roadmap/) by Roman Pichler.

However, I made some changes to mine and it has been received pretty well.  I have attached a copy of the final design below.

Obviously you can customise your own headings but the most useful boxes are typically the **Features**, **Stakeholders** and **Milestones** since they align to **who** is getting **what** and roughly **when**.

[image]